# How to make 3d background for an android game

Tags: android

I have started creating a 3d android game and of course this is my first experience in game development.I found out many tutorials and created a man like model in 3d as .md2 file and inserted animation into it. And now i got a perfect hero to make my game.

Now I want to show like he walks and the background was moving backwards. Please suggest me **how can i create 3d background and make it move backwards** so it will appear like perfectly he walks. Many more thanks for reading this and its great if u suggest any answer, so that my long search will comes to end. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made moving the background by using the SkyBox, i created a box and make it moved by moving the scene.camera() position value. and use blender to create a 3d Model

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one library to made it for you i have a website with a lot of libraries for android try one and give some feedback

[Android Libraries](http://www.openintents.org/en/libraries)

sorry for my bad english.